# Error C244 '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been looking at a lot of questions similar to mine but all of the answers are about how something is just wrong in the code. So I've been looking in mine and I can't find anything wrong with it. Though I guess it makes sense since I'm just starting out with C++. Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int Main = MessageBox(NULL, "Testing", "Testing", MB_YESNO);
{
if (Main == IDYES) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Testing2", "Testing", NULL)

    break;
}
else if (Main == IDNO) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Testing3", "Testing", NULL)

    break;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really don't see anything wrong with that?

Comment: I don't. I am new to coding though, so there is probably is something

Comment: One correct way to express the `main` function is like `int main() { YourStatementsHere; }`. Another correct way is like `auto main() -> int { YourStatementsHe3re; }`. The latter newer notation is more to write for `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program needs to define a function called `main`. The `main` function is what gets called by the environment when your program starts running.

(`main` and `Main` are distinct identifiers, but I suggest that using the name `Main` for an object could be confusing.)

The definition of the `main` function should look like this:

```
int main() {
    // code goes here
}
```

The `#include` directives are fine where they are, but everything else should be inside the definition of `main`.

More complex structures are possible (for example you can have file-scope declarations and multiple function definitions), but this should get you started.

Comment: I had a similar question to the one I have right now with another error, and they suggested that I have my code like how it is above. If they are wrong and you are right, what should I make it look like?

Comment: @EthanEllsworth: If you're referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40232332/827263), nobody suggested using the name `Main`. The code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40232594/827263) is meant to be *part of* your program. You still need to enclose it in a `main` function, as I described. See the comment that says `// code goes here`? That's where your code goes.

Comment: Ugh thank you so much I have been trying to figure this out for ages.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should like something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){

 int result = MessageBox(NULL, "Testing", "Testing", MB_YESNO);

 if (result == IDYES){
  MessageBox(NULL, "Testing2", "Testing", NULL)
 }
 else if (result == IDNO){
  MessageBox(NULL, "Testing3", "Testing", NULL)
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except that it should be indented consistently.